# Twig not showing utf8 characters with doctrine object (SQL server)

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm having trouble displaying some characters when i render a twig template. I'm getting my data from SQL server

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$newsData = $em->getRepository("EstadisticasBundle:Novedades")->findAll();
return $this->render("EstadisticasBundle:index:index.html.twig",array("news" => $newsData));
```

And when I use it in my twig I do it like this

```
    {% set i = 0 %}
    {% for i in 0.. news|length-1 %}
    {% set novedad = news[i] %}
{{ novedad.detalle }}
    {% endfor %}
```

And it doesn't display special characters. If i use |raw it displays like this: "2012 Veinte a�os".

I'm not having any problem showing the characters when i use die() with print or when I write special characters on my twig. It's only happening on the array that's the object that resulted from the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed, it was my bad i thought my DB charset was UTF8 but it wasn't (since I didn't create this DB). I fixed it using

```
    {{ novedad.detalle|convert_encoding('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware when defining charset for Sql Server driver on doctrine2 dbal connection in Symfony2 config.yml.

For pdo_mysql driver charset parameter is:

charset:  UTF8

But for sqlsrv driver charset is:

charset: **UTF-8**

Beware and remember type the hyphen "-"

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
          default:
            driver:   sqlsrv
            host:     %database_host%
            port:     1433
            dbname:   yourdatabasename
            user:     %database_user%
            password: %database_password%
            charset:  UTF-8
```